# How can I fix error 403 on python rest api?

Tags: python, json, api

I don't have much experience with API's. I'm currently working on a Python program using the following api: https://uk.api.just-eat.io/docs#section/Just-Eat-API.

I'm focusing on retrieving json data by postal code: https://uk.api.just-eat.io/docs#operation/SearchByPostcode

```
import requests
import json


response = requests.get("https://uk.api.just-eat.io/restaurants/bypostcode/NW32YT")
print(response.json())
print(response.status_code)
```

When i execute the above I receive the following message:

403

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mari/python/./api.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(response.json())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I was having issues getting the json data but yesterday evening, the status code was 200 and I was able to see the json data from my terminal. Am i missing something in my code? or is the the api unstable?

-Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't send any authentication and receive a 403 (Forbidden).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `Authorization` header as shown in the API [documentation](https://uk.api.just-eat.io/docs#section/Just-Eat-API). If you do not have an API Key you will need to request one from them.

```
PUT https://uk-partnerapi.just-eat.io/orders/abcd1234 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: JE-API-KEY abcd123456789
```

To do this with the requests library you can change your request to

```
requests.get("https://uk.api.just-eat.io/restaurants/bypostcode/NW32YT", headers={'Authorization': 'JE-API-KEY <MY_TOKEN>'})
```